# How to make a vertical text in photoshop

Tags: text, photoshop

I would like to know how can I make this type of text in photoshop. I've tried "vertical text", but it's not what I was looking for...

[image]

Your reply will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Google search on "rotate text photoshop" would give you a lot of answers.

Comment: Yea, it did. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these simple steps to accomplish what you want.

**Type a text that you want**
[image: Type a text that you want]

```
**`ctrl+T` and right click on it, select ccw 90Deg**
```

[image: ctrl+T and right click on it, select ccw 90Deg]
**Here you are :)**
[image: Here you are]

Let me know any further query on this, hope this will be helpful to you..